# Detecting USB and Floppy Drives' Letters via VBScript

Tags: vbscript, drives

I have a Vb-script which store all removable drives' letters into a variable, As you know it contains both floppy and USB drives, I want to seperate them, I mean I want to store USB Drives' Letters in a variable and Floppy ones into another variable,

Here is the script:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

Removable = ""
For Each objDisk in colDisks
  if objDisk.DriveType = 2 then
    if Removable > "" then
      Removable = Removable & ";"
    end if
    Removable = Removable & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
  end if
Next
```

I'm using a software which can call VBScript. But it only support some kind of them like which I posted. So How can I do what I told?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check objDisk.MediaType. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll find a list of MediaTypes; at a first glance MediaType 1 ... 10 indicates a 'normal' floppy; in a quick check on my (virtual) machine, an USB drive showed a MediaType of Null (not even Zero for Unknown), so you'll have do be careful. At a second glance (talking about carefull): most defined media types identify floppies (some of them exotic). BTW - what about USB floppy drives?

---

As I can't test on a 'real' computer, you'll have to double check the following code:

```
Const cnRemovableDisk =  2
Const cnMTypeUnknown  =  0
Const cnMTypeNoFloppy = 11
Const cnMTypeFixedHD  = 12
Dim strComputer   : strComputer       = "."
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Dim colDisks      :  Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")
Dim Removable     : Removable = ""
Dim Floppy        : Floppy    = ""
Dim USBDrive      : USBDrive  = ""
Dim objDisk
For Each objDisk in colDisks
  If objDisk.DriveType = cnRemovableDisk Then
     Removable = Removable & ";" & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
     Select Case True
       Case IsNull( objDisk.MediaType )
          WScript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID, "has MediaType null - assuming USB Drive."
          USBDrive = USBDrive & ";" & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
       Case objDisk.MediaType = cnMTypeNoFloppy
          WScript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID, "has MediaType 11 - assuming USB Drive."
          USBDrive = USBDrive & ";" & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
       Case objDisk.MediaType = cnMTypeUnknown
          WScript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID, "has MediaType 0 - assuming USB Drive."
          USBDrive = USBDrive & ";" & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
       Case objDisk.MediaType = cnMTypeFixedHD
          WScript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID, "has MediaType 12 - how can this happen?"
       Case Else
          WScript.Echo objDisk.DeviceID, "has MediaType", objDisk.MediaType, " - surely some kind of floppy."
          Floppy   = Floppy   & ";" & objDisk.DeviceID & "\"
     End Select
  End If
Next
Removable = Mid( Removable, 2 )
Floppy    = Mid( Floppy   , 2 )
USBDrive  = Mid( USBDrive , 2 )
WScript.Echo "Removable:", Removable
WScript.Echo "Floppy:   ", Floppy
WScript.Echo "USBDrive: ", USBDrive
```

my output is:

```
A: has MediaType 5  - surely some kind of floppy.
F: has MediaType null - assuming USB Drive.
Removable: A:\;F:\
Floppy:    A:\
USBDrive:  F:\
```

The null MediaType of my USBDrive may be a freakish accident. I tried to make tinkering with the evaluating of the MediaType easy by using a "Select Case **True**" control structure. VBScript will test the conditions of the Cases until the first true one, execute the corresponding statement(s), and 'break' to the End Select. So adding special cases and/or reordering cases is straightforward - just keep the IsNull check at first position.

Comment: Hi Ekkehard.Horner, Well Done Man :) Huuuuuuuuge Thanks. It is working fine. You are great :) Can you give me your mail please?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this query

```
set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType=2")
```

For further details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277765/finding-usb-drive-letter-with-vbscript) link. Best of luck