# When an encrypted USB drive is plugged, how can I use WMI to find the 'launcher' logical disk?

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, disk

I am using WMI to determine when various forms of media are plugged/put in (USB drives, CDs, etc). However, encrypted drives such as 'SanDisk Enterprise FIPS USB' do something funky: it looks like they represent themselves as a CD drive from which an unlocking application can be launched. When the unlocking utility is finished, the new USB logical disk is available for read/write.  So the order of events as I am seeing them from WMI is:

1. USB is inserted
2. Win32_DiskDrive object is created (see \.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 below)
3. distinct Win32_LogicalDisks are created, one I copied below (G:), and holds the launcher, the other (M:, in my case) is the drive that will eventually be accessable.

**BUT**, no Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition entries exist until after the utility has run, which is the usual way to locate volumes from a hardware ID. After much googleing and [some trial and error](http://savant7.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/keyboardsmasher.gif), I haven't been able to find an architecturally sound method of associating PHYSICALDRIVE2 to G:. The general consensus online is that you shouldn't expect such mappings to exist, because physical media need not have partitions or volumes, etc, but in my case I basically know it *does* exist, and would error out in some meaningful way if the expected mapping were missing.

At this point, my only strategy is to enumerate all the volumes and just look for the appropriate file in all CD drives, maybe keeping track of any such devices that have been recognized after my encrypted USB drive was connected. Obviously this is an ugly hack. Suggestions?

```
TargetInstance = 
instance of Win32_LogicalDisk
{
    Caption = "G:";
    CreationClassName = "Win32_LogicalDisk";
    Description = "CD-ROM Disc";
    DeviceID = "G:";
    DriveType = 5;
    MediaType = 11;
    Name = "G:";
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
};

instance of Win32_DiskDrive
{
    Caption = "SanDisk Enterprise FIPS USB Device";
    ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
    ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
    CreationClassName = "Win32_DiskDrive";
    Description = "Disk drive";
    DeviceID = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2";
    FirmwareRevision = "6.61";
    Index = 2;
    InterfaceType = "USB";
    Manufacturer = "(Standard disk drives)";
    MediaLoaded = TRUE;
    Model = "SanDisk Enterprise FIPS USB Device";
    Name = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE2";
    Partitions = 0;
    SerialNumber = "u";
    Signature = 0;
    Status = "OK";
    SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a USB 3G dongle that worked in a similar way.

It presented itself to the computer as two entirely separate devices: a CD-ROM drive and a 3G dongle.  In your case it's a CD-ROM drive and a hard drive.

Windows thinks `G:` is actually a physical CD-ROM drive.  `G:` isn't a partition of `PHYSICALDISK2`.

This is why you can't find a direct connection between `G:` and `PHYSICALDISK2`: there isn't one.

If you dig deep enough you could show that the CD-ROM and the disk are on the same USB bus.  I don't know if you could conclusively demonstrate via software that they are actually the same device.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda had most of that worked out. I feel like there *should* be information that connects PHYSICALDISK2 to the drives windows mounted in response to its connection, hoping it does exist and someone here knows about it :)

Comment: But G: isn't mounted in response to PHYSICALDISK2 being connected.  G: is mounted in response to a (pretend) CD-ROM being plugged in.  There really isn't a connection.

Comment: But there is storage on G:; when I double click it in explorer, I am presented with a set of files, so there must be a link somewhere between PHYSICALDISK2 and G:.

Comment: That doesn't follow.  My USB 3G dongle had storage (basically the setup program) on its fake CD-ROM device.  But the files obviously weren't stored on the 3G device.  There's no necessary connection between the CD-ROM storage and the flash storage.  As far as Windows is concerned you have plugged in two separate storage devices.  It's possible that, internally, your USB stick implements the CD-ROM as a read-only partition of the flash, but this fact wouldn't be visible to Windows.  And it's more likely that the actual implementation is separate "fake CD device" + "flash storage device".

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, so maybe I am/was misunderstanding what PHYSICALDISK represents. I would be okay using identifying information for the USB port the device is plugged into, but I didn't see that information readily available through any of the WMI objects. Also, it is interesting to note that when I run the launcher on G:, it 'knows' that the M: logical disk was set up for use by the USB drive. I wonder what mechanism they use to find this volume from the launcher if they are viewed as 2 unrelated devices?

Comment: I guess the setup program on G: identifies its associated flash drive by checking the USB device ID of any drive letters backed by USB devices.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280735/292432) suggests that WMI is frequently useless for associating drive letters and USB devices.  [This article](http://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number/) explains how to get the USB device path from a drive letter using the setup API.

Comment: Can't say I'm overly fond of the latter article's solution...I think I've seen the first one in my research. It doesn't sound like there is a magic bullet here.