# vbscript to copy file from an external disk

Tags: windows, vbscript

A friend and I started building a VBScript that with the goal to copy any opened files/some specific format of docs (like pdf, pptx) when we insert an external hard disk or USB on the computer.  We got our script as far as only copying all docs of a specific format from one the external hard disk/USB to my computer, but we must manually execute the script after inserting the external hard disk/USB.

What we would like the script to do:

1. Start automatically when an external hard disk/USB is inserted
2. Don't show a pop up after the copy
3. Possibily only copy the files (pdf,jpeg,pptx) that are opened by the user

Here is what we've done so far:

```
' foreach.vbs
' Testing the for each function on files
'

' BEGIN

' Create a File System Object to handle files and folders
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Some vars
src = "C:\" ' The source of search, should be changed before use
dest = "c:\temp\1\" ' destination where we will copy files to

' It would be a bright idead to force and/or create dest before
' starting copy
fso.CreateFolder(dest)

Set ofolder = fso.GetFolder(src) ' set as object
' get all files inside the specified folder
Set allfiles = ofolder.Files 
' Enter a For Each Loop that will process each of the files
For Each sfile in allfiles
' Better get all extensions in lower case
If LCASE(fso.GetExtensionName(sfile.Name)) = "bat" then
' Print out what we find
wscript.echo sfile.Name
fso.CopyFile sfile, dest
End If
Next
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'any opened files'? Your script is just copying files from one place to another, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with inserting external disk - the destination of the external disk could change based on what drive letters are available as well...

Comment: By 'any opned files' I mean any documents open like a picture or a pdf.....Yeah it doesn't have inserting external disk but it's because I don't know how to do it and this why I'm asking you guys @Chris

Comment: ??? @Chris  Is it more clear ?

Comment: Sorry no; I don't think I'll be able to help much here.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, your actual question is **How to detect a USB drive has been plugged in**?

You'll need some event driven language to do this, not VBScript unfortunately. 
But if you don't want to go with programming, why not using [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

P.S. Actually, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277765/finding-usb-drive-letter-with-vbscript) (I not like the infinite cycle, but) is a possible answer.