# check if drive is realy a USB ussing batch

Tags: batch-file, usb

I have a random number thats generated and placed in a text file. i would like that file to be saved automaticaly to a USB drive only.

Is there a way in batch to ensure that the file is saved to USB only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. You will need to use a real programming language, or maybe vbscript at the very least, and even then it's very hard to ensure you are actually getting real USB drives.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022696/detecting-usb-and-floppy-drives-letters-via-vbscript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277765/finding-usb-drive-letter-with-vbscript) for some vb samples.

Then if you do, you can use batch to call the script using `cscript.exe`.